# Show that if $A,B$ are $2\times2$ matrices, then $(AB-BA)^2$ commutes with all $2\times2$ matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I tried to write it all out, but it becomes really messy... Is there a more elegant way to do it?

Note that I don't know about dimensions, vector spaces & bases yet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$AB-BA$ has trace zero, so has the form $\pmatrix{u&v\\w&-u}$.
What happens when you square such a matrix?

Comment: then we will get a scalar matrix , and a scalar matrix commutes with every matrix.

Comment: Wow! I thought it was gonna be simpler than what I did, but this is just slick. Thanks!